# How to list kind deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I've deployed a [Istio](https://istio.io/) VirtualService:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: helloweb
spec:
  hosts:
    - 'helloweb.dev'
  gateways:
    - gateway
  http:
    - route:
      - destination:
          host: helloweb.default.svc.cluster.local
          port:
            number: 3000
```

and would like to display on the screen like:

```
kubectl get svc
NAME              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
greeter-service   ClusterIP   10.233.35.214   <none>        3000/TCP   4h38m
helloweb          ClusterIP   10.233.8.173    <none>        3000/TCP   4h38m
kubernetes        ClusterIP   10.233.0.1      <none>        443/TCP    8h
```

How to display the VirtualServices?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly but if you want to just list virtual services you can do this:

```
kubectl get virtualservices
```

VirtualService is just typical CRD.